# Cambiar color de td mediante una etiqueta <a>

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo el siguiente código para validar una etiqueta `<a>` que hace la función de un botón para activar y desactivar.

Lo que quiero es que cuando yo lo presione el color también cambie en el td y no solo en la etiqueta. Ya intenté dándole el if y else al mismo td y dándole estilo pero no se cambia, solo la etiqueta.

Código `<td>`:

```
<td>
<?php 
if($course['status']=="1") 
echo 
"Close: <a href=desactivate.php?id=".$course['id']." class='btn red'></a>";
else 
echo 
"Open: <a href=activate.php?id=".$course['id']." class='btn green'></a>";
?>
</td>
```

Código php de *activate.php*:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jmc");

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
  
$course_id=$_GET['id'];
  
$sql="UPDATE `rampas` SET `status`=1 WHERE id='$course_id'";
  
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
  
header('location: index.php');
?>
```

Código php de *desactivate.php*:

```
<?php
  
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jmc");

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
  
$course_id=$_GET['id'];
  
$sql="UPDATE `rampas` SET `status`=0 WHERE id='$course_id'";
  
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
  
header('location: index.php');
?>
```

Y así es como se ve funcionando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu etiqueta `td`, debes agregar una etiqueta `div` y darle los estilos que desees, ya que el `div` encierra todo lo que está dentro del `td`, sería algo así:

```
<td>
 <?php 
 if($course['status']=="1") 
  echo 
  "<div style='background: #fab6b1;'> Close: <a href=desactivate.php?id=".$course['id']." class='btn red'></a></div>";
 else 
  echo 
  "<div style='background: #c8fac3;'> Open: <a href=activate.php?id=".$course['id']." class='btn green'></a></div>";
 ?>
</td>
```

Comment: si te sirvió la respuesta, recuerda verificarla para que así los demás que tengan tu misma duda sepan que te funcionó con la respuesta dada.

Comment: Me funciono de maravilla muchas gracias